# ng-multiselect-dropdown onDeSelectAll() not working

Tags: angular

I am using ng-multiselect dropdown in my angular code. While all the onSelect, onSelectAll, onDeSelect methods are working fine, onDeselctAll method doesn't receive the array of items deselected. I checked in the official site but it was of no use : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown. 
Any idea where I might be going wrong? PFB the code snippet:

**.html file**

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown *ngIf="filteredSids.length > 0"
                                             [data]="filteredSids"
                                             [disabled]="false"
                                             [(ngModel)]="selectedSids"
                                             (onSelect)="selectedSIDs($event); onItemSelect($event)"
                                             (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
                                             (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"
                                             (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)"
                                             [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                                             formControlName="sidControl">
                    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

**.ts file**

```
onSelectAll(selectedSIDList: Array<string>): void {
        selectedSIDList.forEach(sid => {
            this.selectedSIDs(sid);
            this.onItemSelect(sid);
        });
    }

    onItemDeSelect(deselectedSID: any): void {
        this.selectedSIDList = this.selectedSIDList.filter(s => s != deselectedSID);

        this.selectedSIDList.forEach(sid => {
            this.onItemSelect(sid);
        });
    }

    onDeSelectAll(items: any){
        console.log(items); // items is an empty array
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/blob/ba0e13f24eaa2f736ec7f8283e23cf41a44d6103/src/ng-multiselect-dropdown/src/multiselect.component.ts#L321), receiving an empty array is the correct behaviour:

```
this.selectedItems = [];
this.onDeSelectAll.emit(this.emittedValue(this.selectedItems));
```

If you want to track the items that are being deselected, you need to find a different way.

Comment: can we stop the default behavior of the onDeSelect() event? I have a scenario when where if I click the "x" on the select item. It will open a popup with values to "Yes" & "No". If I click no, it should retain the selected value. Else , it should remove the value.

Comment: Hi @Vijay, I have also the same requirement. Are you able to handle it in ng-multiselect-dropdown in angular. if Yes then can you please share the code ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ng-multiselect-dropdown
     [placeholder]="'Select Categories'"
     [settings]="dropdownSettings"
     [data]="collectionList"
     [(ngModel)]="selectedCollection"
     (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
     (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
     (onDeSelectAll)="onItemDeSelect($event)">
   </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Then in .ts file add function

```
 onItemDeSelect(items: any){
  this.selectedCollection = []
  this.getProductList()
 }
```